# How to check state of exq job in phoenix framework?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am using exq as background processing in phoenix framework. Is there a way to check state of exq jobs using job_id to know if it has been completed or failed or what? I went through documentation but there’s not much info about it.

Answer (score 1):

`Exq` has [`Exq.Api`](https://hexdocs.pm/exq/Exq.Api.html) that is documented. I would suggest you need [`Exq.Api.find_job/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/exq/Exq.Api.html#find_job/3).

Unfortunately, the documentation does not provide links to the source, so [here it is](https://github.com/akira/exq/blob/master/lib/exq/api.ex).

Comment: It takes `pid` as argument which is not available for me when jobs are running on multiple VMs.

Comment: I am not sure I follow. `Exq` is fully _Sidekiq_-compatible, meaning it uses _Redis_ as a backend. Jobs are stored in _Redis_, no matter how many VMs do you have to access it. Get your local `Exq.Api` process’ pid and use it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @mudasobwa, I got it working here's complete example for someone whose wondering same.

```
job_pid = Application.get_env(:exq, :name) |> Exq.Api.Server.server_name
job_id = "935440ba-44c7-47d6-a973-2e23860dc54c"
{:ok, queued_for_retry_job} =  Exq.Api.find_retry(job_pid, job_id)

Exq.Api.find_failed(job_pid, job_id)
Exq.Api.find_jobs(job_pid, "queue" ,job_id)
```

All exq api function can be found on https://hexdocs.pm/exq/Exq.Api.html